# MySQL UPSERT not recognizing alias

Tags: mysql, left-join, upsert

I have a query that performs an UPSERT (Insert - but if exists, update).

MySQL complains it isn't valid, here is the query:

```
insert into
    mytable (user_id, num_products_observed, num_purchased_percent)
    (select
        A.user_id,
        B.total 'num_products_observed',
        case 
            when A.purchased is null then 0
            else A.purchased/B.total
        end 'num_purchased_percent'
     from
         (select user_id, count(prod_observed) 'total' from products where user_id = ? ) B
         left join (select user_id, count(prod_purch) 'purchased' from products_purchased) A on B.user_id = A.user_id
    ) newsum -- <--- ISSUE IS HERE
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    num_products_observed = newsum.num_products_observed,
    num_purchased_percent = newsum.num_purchased_percent
```

I hope this makes sense to you. The issue is at the line which reads `) newsum`. MySql complains about the alias I'm giving the table. user_id is unique in this table (`mytable`).

It IS possible that B.total is null, in which case everything in newsum is null - which is fine, then I don't want to insert or update anything (or an update with user_id and zeros for all would be fine too).

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: There's nothing in manual about being able to alias the select (and that select should not be in brackets). Can't you refer to "A" and "B" tables in the "ON DUPLICATE KEY" again, as opposed to referencing the INSERT SELECT table?

Comment: FYI, you should be using `backticks` instead of 'quotes' for your alias names, if applicable.  And since your names don't require quoting (because they don't have special characters), don't use them at all, to ensure compatibility of your queries against other servers that don't support backticks.  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use VALUES statements.

You can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement

[dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)